# What is the difference in proper nutrition for different sports?

Tags: nutrition

I've been trying to look up information on the internet and in real life for proper nutrition, but every article, ebook, personal trainers and enthusiasts seem to have completely different opinions on what constitutes a proper nutrition. A lot of the information around it is based around marketing which leaves me clueless as to where I can find the right information, and more importantly how do I know that the information is correct?

One of the things I want to know is does a proper nutrition depend on what sport you do, and  in particular how should my nutrition be for optimizing my badminton performance? Should this follow a similar nutrition scheme as for weight lifting? (I actually do multiple sports as well as weight lifting, but focus is mainly on badminton)

Answer (score 2):

Proper nutrition depends to a large extent on your sport/ physical activity of choice. People training for aesthetics need high protein and low carb diets, so their muscles look sharp and defined. They don't always need high carb for energy apart from pre- and post- workout. For badminton or anything that requires a lot of stamina and running around, you need a little bit more carbs and you might be able to ease up a little on the protein intake. But in general the basic structure of nutritional balance doesn't change. It is a good idea to go for a 40-40-20 split between proteins, carbs, and good fats. Go for some fruit like banana before playing so that they keep you going during the activity.